# SSLstrip with dnsmasq How to Use

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables

I believe this is an appropriate question for this SE but please move it if its not.

I have followed [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/A-Grey-Hat/?ALLSTEPS) to create an AP that re-routes all trafic to **10.0.0.1** where my own website is served. The problem is that because of HTTPS and SSL most sites will just fail to connect instead of showing my site.

So I installed **sslstrip** to avoid this. However, when I ran it, nothing changed. I am not really sure how to use it and the man pages did not help. I don't really know what port my server is on.

Here are my revelant configurations:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo    
iface lo inet loopback    
iface eth0 inet dhcp    
iface wlan0 inet static address 10.0.0.1    
netmask 255.255.255.0    
broadcast 255.0.0.0    
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

**iptables**

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT    
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT    
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT    
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -p udp --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT    
sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -j DROP    
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules"
```

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log    
address=/#/10.0.0.1    
interface=wlan0    
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10, 10.0.0.250,12h   
no-resolv    
log-queries
```

Comment: Would I have to add sudo iptables -i wlan0 -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT?

Answer (score 0):

SSLstrip only makes it so that if you're already on HTTP, you won't end up on HTTPS. If a connection starts out on HTTPS, SSLstrip can't do anything. Modern browsers have preloaded HSTS lists with many popular sites, pretty much for the sole reason of making it impossible to do the very thing you're trying to do.